# Graphics 3D - manipulate

Tags: graphics, manipulate, graphics3d

Basing on this code:

```
box1 = GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}], ShearingMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]]
box2 = GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{1, 1, 0}], ShearingMatrix[-Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]]
Graphics3D@{box1, box2}
```

I would like to create a 3D figure (two joined cuboids) with adjustable bend angle and dimensions of cuboids {a,b,c} (`Manipulate`)

Comment: And what problems did you find?

Comment: 1) unable to set the adjustable {a,b,c} dimensions for both cuboids simulatneously
2) cuboids do not maintain "stuck" under the chang of bend angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{gt, sc, sh, re} = {GeometricTransformation, ScalingTransform, 
                    ShearingTransform, ReflectionTransform}; 
{x, y} = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}; 

Manipulate[ t = gt[gt[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}], sc[{a, b, c}]], sh[p, x, y]]; 
            Graphics3D[{t, gt[t, re[y]]}, Axes -> True],
 {a, 1, 2}, {b, 1, 2}, {c, 1, 2}, {p, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How would it look like if such parametrization for `Cuboid` was introduced:
`Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}], {Abs[-1/Sqrt[6] +a], Abs[-1/Sqrt[6] + a], Sqrt[2/3]}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 box1 = GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}],
                                ShearingMatrix[ θ, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]];
 box2 = GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{1, 1, 0}], 
                                ShearingMatrix[-θ, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]];
 Graphics3D@{box1, box2},
 {{θ, 0}, -π/4, π/4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am looking for constant operation that will not separate the cuboids when changing the bend angle.